# Django rest framework use router with pk in URL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use DRF on my project and have some routes like:

```
router.register(r'user', views.UserView, basename='user')
router.register(r'user/{pk}/note', views.NoteView, basename='user')
```

So I want to have an opportinuty to do GET,POST,PUT etc. actions with a note. Some part of NoteView:

```
class NoteView(ModelViewSet, CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Note.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return NoteListSerializer
        return NoteSerializer
```

But it doesn't work with this route, how should I define it?

**Solution:**
Define firstly user router, then add a note route to it:

```py
user_router = router.register(r'user', views.UserView, basename='user')
user_router.register(r'note', views.NoteView, basename='note', parents_query_lookups=['pk'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch the user `pk` and use it in your view class methods. I'm guessing you want to use only the notes related to the user id here as the queryset?

In that case you want to do is this:

```py
class NoteView(
    ModelViewSet,
    CreateModelMixin,
    RetrieveModelMixin,
    UpdateModelMixin,
    DestroyModelMixin
):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]

    def get_queryset(self, pk=None):
        return Note.objects.filter(user__id=pk)

    def list(self, request, pk=None):
        ...

    def create(self, request, pk=None):
        ...

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        ...

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        ...

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return NoteListSerializer
        return NoteSerializer
```

**EDIT** I'm not 100% sure DRF's `get_queryset` can have this custom route argument. If this solution doesn't work you might just grab the route argument from the request with:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    user_id: int = self.request.query_params.get(pk)
    return Note.objects.filter(user__id=user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I go to "../user/1/note" I had 404 error for some reason. It looks like I'm configuring the url incorrectly and DRF understands this {pk} part as a usual text.

Comment: I found a solution!

I just need to add:


`user_router = router.register(r'user', views.UserView, basename='user')
user_router.register(r'note', views.NoteView, basename='note', parents_query_lookups=['pk'])`